# Android - Changing colours in override methods

Tags: java, android

I'm making a drawing app. I have two brushes `(img_brush and img_brush2)`. The initial colour is set to black in `PaintView()` `(on the line 'this.colour = Color.BLACK;')`. What I want to do is set different colours for both brushes in the override '`(onClick`) methods, for example blue for `img_brush` and red for `img_brush2`, how can I do it? This is the code I have got:

```
public class Draw_Activity extends Activity {

private PaintView pv;
protected View layout;
protected int progress;
protected Dialog dialog;
protected Dialog textdialog;
private String[] arrImagesStrings;
protected float stroke = 6;
int postion;
private String fileName;
private int ColorAh = Color.BLACK;
String Foldername;
RelativeLayout re;
private AdView mAdView;
ImageView img_brush, img_brush2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawpic_activity);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    re = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rell);
    img_brush = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_brush);
    img_brush2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_brush2);

    this.fileName = null;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.pv = new PaintView(this);
    re.addView(pv);
    //setContentView(this.pv);
    this.pv.togglePencil(true);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Foldername = i.getStringExtra("Folder");


    img_brush.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Draw_Activity.this.pv.togglePencil(true);
        }
    });

    img_brush2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Draw_Activity.this.pv.togglePencil(true);
        }
    });
}

//for color

private void showColorPickerDialogDemo() {

    int initialColor = Color.WHITE;

    ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog(Draw_Activity.this, initialColor, new OnColorSelectedListener() {

        public void onColorSelected(int color) {

            Draw_Activity.this.pv.setColor(color);
        }

    });
    colorPickerDialog.show();
}

private PaintView(Context c) {
    super(c);

    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); // to save images

    this.context = c;
    this.colour = Color.BLACK;

    this.path = new Path();
    this.bmpPaint = new Paint();
    this.paint = new Paint();
    this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    this.paint.setDither(true);
    this.paint.setColor(this.colour);
    this.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    this.paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    this.paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    this.paint.setStrokeWidth(50);

    this._paintBlur = new Paint();
    this._paintBlur.set(paint);
    this._paintBlur.setAntiAlias(true);
    this._paintBlur.setDither(true);
    this._paintBlur.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    this._paintBlur.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    this._paintBlur.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    this._paintBlur.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FA2B2B"));
    this._paintBlur.setStrokeWidth(6.0F);
    this._paintBlur.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10.0F, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.OUTER));

    this.bitmapforground = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    this.bitmapforground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.color.textbg);


}

public void setColor(int c) {
    this.paint.setColor(c);
    this.colour = c;
}

protected int getColor() {
    return this.colour;
}
}
```

Comment: Whats the actual question?